# Why would the Bifröst Bridge in Thor be able to destroy other worlds?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-2011

I was under the impression that the Bifröst Bridge is just a bridge (wormhole) between the 9 worlds, and yet in the movie it can be used as a weapon.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The bridge output an enormous amount of energy, and when turned to full power, that energy was apparently destructive.

It's probably something akin to how if you stand five feet from a fire, you are warmed, but if you stand five inches from the same fire, you are burned: the intensity of the energy transfer was increased by orders of magnitude, turning the 'bridge' into a 'Death Star'.

It beats the hell out of a [kawoosh](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Kawoosh).

edit: Additional Information: There's really no scientific reason for it, other than the increase in the energy transfer, because the [Einstein-Rosen Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole) is a purely theoretical concept.  As such, its properties are only postulated, and scriptwriters can and will twist them until they serve the purpose of the story.  Hence, the wormhole becomes a massive magnetic storm, with multicolored lightning and the potential for genocide.

The real question is why did the Asgard build their wormhole junction with the capability to output enough power to destroy a realm?  And why would the Frost Giants be stupid enough to wage war against an enemy who could eradicate them in the space of an hour, from beyond their own effective reach?

Comment: Wormholes are serious business.

Comment: **The real question is why did the Asgard build their wormhole junction with the capability to output enough power to destroy a realm?** why are cars built with the power capacity to kill people. or rockets that can go to the moon can also launch warheads that can level cities. anyone, with the will and intent, can use anything for destructive purposes.

Comment: @Xantec: assuredly...but I don't know of any civilian vehicles that have an engine that puts out enough horsepower to melt the tires.  There's a difference between taking technology and weaponizing it or misusing it and overengineering something to the point where it becomes dangerous during normal use.  They seem to have gone with the Tim Taylor approach to interstellar travel.

Comment: Wormholes can't be under-engineered such that they function but cannot be dangerous.  They're at minimum, devices that bend 4D space-time enough to connect two distant points, which is a wildly powerful thing to do.  Farscape has many examples of how crazy such a device could be.

Comment: @Jeff: The bridge does not seem anywhere close to "over-engineered". And it certainly was not "dangerous during normal use". At least in the movie, it was modified in some way (the frost that grew in it) before becoming dangerous. Not to mention that it may have been designed and even used to go farther than the nine realms. You may as well criticize pencils for being able to poke your eye out. Heck, you could be killed with a sharpened pencil.

Comment: @Wayne: Heimdall and others explicitly state that if they turned the bridge to full power it would destroy the Frost Giant world.  This was far before it was 'modified' by having frost grow over it.  That frost 'modified' the bridge about as much as dew 'modifies' flowers.

Comment: @Jeff: From my memory (of the movie), Loki made a big deal of the frost growing inside the sphere, implying to me that he was somehow magically enhancing its beam. I may be wrong.

Comment: @Jeff Your comment about cars being built with enough horsepower to melt the tires reminded me of something; The Bugatti Veyron actually can do just that. It has 1000 horsepower to the tires, and is capable of topping out at 268 mph. At that rate, the tires will begin to melt after fifteen minutes, but that's fine; the gas runs out after nine.

Comment: @GabeWillard: So you prove my point - even the one car that you know of that CAN melt its own tires can't actually melt its own tires, because it'd run out of gas before it got hot enough.  You could modify it to add a larger tank (or extra tanks) but in normal use it isn't over-engineered enough to be such a hazard (given a trained operator).

Comment: I got the impression that the Bifrost was some form of matter-energy-matter conversion along with a wormhole. Matter on one end is converted to energy before being passed through the wormhole. In normal function, the Bifrost would transport a single person to be reconstructed on the other side (akin to passing a single packet of data). Loki's frost kept the Bifrost permanently on so that it would constantly convert matter to energy and direct it toward Jotunheim, turning into a massive ray of destruction (akin to a data flood).

Comment: @Xantec actually a powerful engine in the right kind of car can indeed melt the tires.

Comment: @FoxMan2099 You may have meant to reply to Jeff. In either case, it is more of a case of the tires being shredded than melted. If you use a set of tires to the point that they get hot enough to soften then they will degrade faster, but they won't melt. The vulcanization process sees to that. Even in tire recycling it isn't possible to just melt them down. They need to be finely shredded and specially processed to de-vulcanize them (assuming you want to recover the rubber).

Comment: Ah but you made my point---engines are powerful enough to destroy tires!!! There's practically no reason to frog it in first and burn rubber (or shred tires!), but some engines are powerful enough to leave streaks of tire on the road and destroy the tires.

Answer (score 5):

The comparison to an automobile or rocket is a good answer. As far as why the frost giants would be that "stupid", I think the question should actually be "Assuming the Jotun are aware of the destructive power of the Bifrost Bridge, why would they wage war against a people who control that much destructive power?" The Asgardians are meant to serve as protectors of the nine realms, which means ALL nine realms, even Jotunheim. We can assume that the Jotun are aware of this, and know that Odin would never use the Bifrost in that way. This is just the kind of attitude and behavior that he was attempting to discourage when he sent Thor to Midgard (Earth) to learn the value of thinking before you act and behaving in a manner befitting the protector of the Nine Realms.

Answer (score 4):

"if you stand five feet from a fire, you are warmed, but if you stand five inches from the same fire, you are burned"

Actually, I tend to think it has more to do with the gravitational forces from Bifrost.  It is, in effect a black hole (as we see when Thor and Loki are hanging off the remainder of the bridge) so if focused properly, say into a small enough point, the gravitational pull needed to warp space would be devastating.